# RSA Decryption with phpseclib is failing

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

I have mobile application that encrypts strings with RSA and sends that encrypted data to PHP web server.

After a search I found that **phpseclib** is used to decrypt **RSA**
Latest version 2.0.

No matter what I do I receive despite error despite used mode

Am i doing something wrong?

What I have tried:

Private key for decryption:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOgIBAAJBAJyHUgC1ijhsETeuoNMh4c4yrFoL4juL/yDderMC9fBd1TFgEoJ5dxzMzdlzVVj7Vc/H/I+k13yY3W0MknS//k8CAwEAAQJAaaL1l57s8lkUYZTL2tFh9+vA32BnxLIdc0ullAwqeJV21wXcEyDA67fbmBywdt+pVKkeO2NU7fD3e+DZREuJ0QIhAPZNo9jirkRl4i/Lv3jWt6SmeUBeyIKK0u4lZiBF9KAZAiEAorDjj2c9WBdP46S9hK7yj0U5/0QHB0pO01j9QSVBvqcCIQDrYre7hqdU5qmLVATgzxMiX5ZxViP53gJHZaZ8IV7vwQIgTTYEGafWjjsqGBC0PQdGaMZi+wnPCB+0/0rpjoRfClsCIBPzZw+lappnVxXHuUoQQeN6uevqSvmgvC42UyA4HABa
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Encrypted message (base64 encoded):

```
SMZiVTAMizngWa5Yg2Xp0F3Coy4cIsLB6mru2rLhxnvS2SC\/rm9pgPVLdA\/hp+1TIbzHZqjc2lnP\nkvzh797WlA==\n
```

PHP sample code:

```
$rsa = new RSA();
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$rsa->loadKey($privateKey); 
echo $rsa->decrypt(base64_decode($strBase64));
```

Result:

```
Notice: Decryption error in C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\phpseclib\phpseclib\phpseclib\Crypt\RSA.php on line 2553
```

Mode:

```
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_OAEP);
```

Result:

```
Notice: Decryption error in C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\phpseclib\phpseclib\phpseclib\Crypt\RSA.php on line 2432
```

Mode:

```
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_NONE);
```

Result:

```
string(128) "I�W��B'q����;k��}�1������=��x���*���_��aq�)�D� '�m{��� ��n���C:��t �E����R=�S�y�3$QC�EV.3C�{�.Y�jx�6��!�e�˱]�I ����S�/�'I�|"
```

Comment: did you decode the base64?

Comment: yes, i decode it.

Comment: I can't test php right now but the private in your question does decrypt the cipher in your question. NO padding is used. The result is a readable ASCII string.

Comment: @JamesKPolk - idk how you're doing your decryption but I'm not able to decrypt the OP's ciphertext. I did `openssl rsautl -decrypt -in encrypted.txt -out plaintext.txt -raw -inkey priv.pem` via the CLI and got a "_data greater than mod len_" back. This makes sense because the ciphertext is 65 bytes long whereas the modulo for the key is 64 bytes long (512 bits)

Comment: @neubert: Are we looking at the same thing? When I base64 decode the encrypted message (using python's base64.b64decode()) that starts with 'SMZ...' I get a 64-byte result thats is (in hex) `48c66255300c8b39e059ae588365e9d05dc2a32e1c22c2c1ea6aeedab2e1c67bd2d920bfae6f6980f54b740fe1a7ed5321bcc766a8dcda59cf92fce1efded694`

Comment: @neubert don't blame me for wanting to know the truth.
Remove the last char of ciphertext - \n (new line)

Comment: @neubert: I see now that the base64 encrypted message contains several invalid escape "\" characters and an embedded newline. Here is the value after removal of those characters: `SMZiVTAMizngWa5Yg2Xp0F3Coy4cIsLB6mru2rLhxnvS2SC/rm9pgPVLdA/hp+1TIbzHZqjc2lnPkvzh797WlA==`

Comment: @JamesKPolk - good catch! I think that's the problem the OP is having!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As James J Polk observed, your base64 encoded string has some bad characters in it. idk what you're using in PHP as your delimiter but this worked for me:

```
$strBase64 = 'SMZiVTAMizngWa5Yg2Xp0F3Coy4cIsLB6mru2rLhxnvS2SC\/rm9pgPVLdA\/hp+1TIbzHZqjc2lnP\nkvzh797WlA==\n';
$strBase64 = str_replace(['\/', '\n'], ['/', ''], $strBase64);
```

If you're using double quotes instead of single quotes do this:

```
$strBase64 = "SMZiVTAMizngWa5Yg2Xp0F3Coy4cIsLB6mru2rLhxnvS2SC\/rm9pgPVLdA\/hp+1TIbzHZqjc2lnP\nkvzh797WlA==\n";
$strBase64 = str_replace(['\/', "\n"], ['/', ''], $strBase64);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rsa = new RSA();
  $rsa->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_OAEP);
  $ciphertext = base64_decode($string);
  $rsa->setMGFHash('sha1');
  $rsa->setHash('sha256');
  $rsa->loadKey($pkey); // public key
  $output = $rsa->decrypt($ciphertext);
 return $output;
```